# Class Not Found Exception with description: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request

Tags: servlets

Error in console:

```
Dec 13, 2015 12:45:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet LoginController
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: flexController.LoginController
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1062)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


my servlet is:
package flexController;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginController
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String un=request.getParameter("username");
        String pw=request.getParameter("password");

        if(un.equals("admin") && pw.equals("admin"))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
 metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>Flex1.1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <description></description>
    <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>flexController.LoginController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

i'm writing just a simple login page using servlet, which will redirect to succes page or error page after login.

Comment: Tested your code.working fine at my end.Do a clean build and try again.How are you calling this servlet?

Comment: Thanks Prince,
its working fine now,
i just deleted the whole project and imported it back.